# How to animate conditionally rendered widgets in Flutter

Tags: android, animation, flutter, dart, widget

I am adding a widget to build tree conditionally, now how can I animate displaying and hiding when **isPlaying** changes?:

```
...
if (isPlaying)
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(200, 255, 255, 255),
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: buttonStroke,
                            width: 1.3,
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
                        ),
                        child: _buildPlayer(),
                      ),
                    ),
```

Comment: tried `Visibility`?

Comment: yes, but I can't get it animated

Comment: and how do you want to animate? maybe simply use `AnimatedSwitcher` that manages most of the work and has nice default properties?